# How to remove/add fields to events view on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

When I update the events list columns/content type the fields change in the calendar view, but not in the events view/or on the web part events.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to remove/add fields to the below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a system page, it's by design, you cannot customize it.